# Reactjs with Parse.com asynchronous loading error? Can't access object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, reactjs

I am building a simple Todo app using React (with Redux) and Parse.  I am having a serious problem understanding asynchronous loading of an object.

Case #1:

```
var todos = this.props.todos;
    console.log(todos) // I see [{TodoClass} {TodoClass}]
    console.log(todos[0]) // I see {id: "xyz123", content: "hello world"}
```

Case #2:

```
var todos = this.props.todos;
    console.log(todos) // I see []
    console.log(todos[0]) // undefined
    console.log(todos[0].id) // error; can't access id
```

Emphasis - todos on server is populated; I am not trying to access empty array, but by adding the access `.id`, todos array becomes empty.

I am stuck.  I suspect the sequence of loading changes when I try to access "id" but I do not know how to fix it. Please suggest fixes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

TodoClass.js:

```
function TodoClass(id, content) {
  this.id = id;
  this.content = content;
}
export default TodoClass
```

By using Parse Query find() Promise, I map the data and store in my TodoClass instance for each "row" of Parse db, and the data to store.  I see the Redux viewer updates correctly.

This is where I load it, TodoList.jsx:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({    
    render: function() {
        var todos = this.props.todos;  <-- Array of TodoClass instances
        var renderData = () => {
            console.log(todos)
            console.log(todos[0])
            //console.log(todos[0].id) <-- Gives me issues.
            var elements = [];
            for (var i = 1; i< 5; i++) {
                elements.push(<BrowseItem key={i} todo={todos[i]}/>)
            };    
            return elements;
         };
         return (
          <div > {renderData()}  </div>
        );
    }
});        
export default connect((state) => {return state})(TodoList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first snipped doesn't error but the second one does is, the latter raises an error when you are trying to access `.id` on `undefined` — which makes sense. If there are no todo items there, you can't get the id of the first item — the item is not there.

Your `render` function should probably check if there are any todos, and return a "loading" / "no todos" placeholder here:

```
render: function() {
  var todos = this.props.todos;
  if (todos.length === 0) {
    return <div>No todos.</div>;
  }
  console.log(...);
  ...
  return <div>{renderData()}</div>
}
```

Comment: Basically, if I "comment out" the last line `console.log(todos[0].id)` then now I see everything I saw in case #1, as identical. Nothing on the db data has changed, so I have 3 parse elements.  I am not trying to access empty array; somehow array becomes empty when `.id` is access attempted. The third line of `console.log()` is affecting the first and second.

Comment: Please note that if you are loading asynchronously, the first time the component is rendered, it will probably see an empty array, and only then update with the loaded todos. It doesn't become "empty" somehow, it always is empty on the first run. The 2nd snippet throws an error and doesn't get updated when an array populates.

Comment: thank you for clarifying. Yes, that is the issue I am trying to solve. It is running asynchronously. If you know a way to get around this issue, please suggest.

Comment: @jbro please re-read my answer. Just check for when an array is empty or not. You could wrap the `[0].id` console log into the `if (todos.length > 0)`

Comment: Arinichi I tried as suggested and it worked great. Conceptually, however, still having difficulty understanding why a simple if-statement allows it to monitor changes in props. My "wrong" thinking is if-statement throws False when there is no item, and render would end its operation, even if the data finally comes in.